# Twig negate starts with

Tags: twig

What is the negation of `starts with` in twig templates ?

I get variabe with url like "account" and dont want to display login button if my url starts with "account".

What is the nagation of starts with in my case ?

```
{% if req starts with 'account' %}
<a href="/account">login</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can negate the expression with `not`. In order this to work with `start withs` u'd need to force `twig` to execute the expression first with parantheses.

```html
{% if not (req starts with 'account') %}
   <a href="/account">login</a>
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/eqjzlu)